# If multiple processes are doing Read/Write on different files. Are these operations considered as Sequential access or Random access?

Tags: multithreading, io, multiprocessing

Consider there are multiple small applications running at the same time, each of them open a few files, each of size 10 MB - 100 MB, load into memory, perform some sorts of calculation, then write the result back to disk on a different file, which is also 10 MB - 100 MB.

My question is: are these read and write operations considered as sequential disk access or random disk access?

If we focus on one application, it seems to be sequential as all file are read from begin to the end, continuously (or from a specific offset to the end).
However if we look at all applications, they are doing file reading and writing all at the same time, which seems to be a random disk access.

Examples on sequential disk access and random disk access, especially in terms of the multi-thread / multi-application scenario will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how many applications or threads do you use to access files.

Sequential access and random access terminology is applicable to the media you are accessing.

Suppose you need to read data block from arbitrary offset from encrypted file which is encrypted by good algorithm (where each subsequent block is encrypted with data dependent on previous block encryption operation).
While you can use seek and read the block you still can't decrypt it (so you can't access it).
Such media as a result does not support random access to the data, i.e. you need to decrypt previous stream to fetch the block at specific offset of the file.
So such media supports only sequential access.

On the other hand your non-ecrypted file can have structured information so you can read the head of file to get geometry of your data and access arbitrary block without reading all previous bytes. 
This is example of random access.

Multiple applications can mix sequential access with random access method to access the data from the same file simultaneously.

If some app uses random access to fetch piece of information from huge file then you can tell that it uses random access for this particular operation but it most likely read some other files as well so it can use both approaches.

So random and sequential accesses are capabilities of media but not properties of application's operations.